# In English you have 'above', 'on', 'over' and 'on top of' but in Italian one word, 'sopra', covers all four meanings

Tags: etymology, prepositions, word-usage, compounds, italian

In Italian if I were to say, "sopra l'albero" (albero = tree) you might rightly ask: "Yes but where, exactly?"

But "[**sopra**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sopra)" is a great word to learn in Italian, not only is it a very flexible preposition of place, you can create a new word by simply tagging a noun, which explains perfectly its meaning. No guess work necessary.

For example:

- *Soprabito* means something you put **over** your clothes. A coat.
- *Sopracciglio* means something **above** your eyelashes. Eyebrows.
- *Soprammobile* something which you put **on top of** a piece of furniture. An ornament.

However, an English person might justify the use of so many different prepositions with similar meanings and *top*[<sup>1</sup>](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119872/in-english-you-have-above-on-over-and-top-but-in-italian-one-word-so#comment245839_119872) by saying they indicate precisely where an object is positioned. In the case of "sopra l'albero" the argument is defeated as soon as anyone mentions **what** and what it is **doing** in connection to the tree. (I hope I have explained myself clearly.) A bird is "sopra l'albero"? Then it must be **on** a tree. A bird is flying "sopra l'albero"? Then it must be **over** the tree. A bird is perched "sopra l'albero"? Then it has to be at the **top**, etc.

My questions are:

- What is the etymology and history behind **above, on, over** and **top**.
- Why was there a need to have these words when as shown *above*, within a specific context, ambiguity in meaning is eliminated.
- Which English words, if any, contain the preposition, **on**, coupled with a concrete noun to form one word.

Comment: 1 - etymonline. 2 - 'why' presumes intention, and in language history there is none. 3 in English, 'super-' is the prefix used, just like Italian.

Comment: Mari, being an Italian I cannot resist to upvote this question, but I'm sure Anglophones cannot deeply understand its sense.

Comment: Some can. It's an interesting question, and illustrates nicely the difference between Romance languages, where almost all the vocabulary comes from Latin, and English, where only half comes from Latin, leaving open other possibilities.

Comment: Preposition meaning depends to a large extent on context and idiomatic usage. We say we are *on* an airliner when we're actually *in* it. We can say we live *on* Lake Michigan when we actually live *near* it. We can also say that someone arrived *on time* (meaning at a designated hour) and also *in time* (at a moment after which some condition would not be met), and either of those can be used to describe the same thing in some circumstances.

Comment: (@Carlo_R. - _Resist_ takes a gerund with Equi, not an infinitive; should be _can't resist upvoting_.)

Comment: But all of the words Mari-Lou mentioned (except _top_, which is a noun, not a preposition) come from [the same PIE root, *uper-](http://web.archive.org/web/20080708222037/http://bartleby.com/61/roots/IE544.html), some via Latin, some via Germanic. We now have the use of both these sets of words in English, where we use them for whatever we please, as we always do with words we borrow from other languages.

Comment: @John, thank you! I'm sure of being not able to learn when one should use the gerund and when the infinitive; but, really, thank you again.

Comment: One correction: _on_ comes from a different [PIE root *an-](http://web.archive.org/web/20080727014647/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE16.html). This root appears to have English cognates from Germanic, Greek, and Slavonic, but not Latin. Which doesn't mean it didn't have cognates, just that none of them got borrowed into English.

Comment: @JohnLawler, as far as I know, only one Latin word that more or less certainly continues the _*anh₃_ root is known: _anhēlō_ ‘expire, desire’. This would probably have become ‘anhale’ (like ‘inhale’ or ‘exhale’) if borrowed into English, but as you say, it wasn’t. The preposition itself seems to have been all but obliterated in all Italic, though. (Note also that ‘above’ comes from both _*anh₃_ and _*(H)uper-_, being ‘on’ + ‘by’ + [a nominal form of] ‘over’.)

Comment: Moreover, su/sopra can also be used to mean "about the..., concerning the..." :S! Above may be translated with the construct "al di sopra".

Comment: (a) For consistency, the title should list four prepositions (one complex): _In English you have 'above', 'on', 'over' and 'on top of'._ (b) I'm guessing that _Soprasoprabito_ **isn't** 'overcoat'. (c) Robusto's comment is nicely illustrated by **on board**, **above board** and **overboard**. And decent folk are **above**, criminologists can write **on**, police can be **on top of** or else taken to task **over**, petty theft.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I'll make the necessary edits you suggested. (b) can also be defined as 'overcoat' (c) fair point, as in Italian those concepts are expressed in completely different ways, and with some difficulty too, I might add.

Comment: Yes - prepositions start off as simple little words showing spatial then temporal relationships, easily classed as lexical words and illustrated in infant grammars, then are soon forced into  lexically-hard-to-define syntactic relational roles galore.

Comment: Including intransitive prepositions, which is what Huddleston and Pullum call the particles in phrasal verbs like _take off_ and _listen up_.

Comment: @Mitch, *super-* is not the same as *supra-*, eg Heller's/Yossarian's play on 'superman'. // MariLouA, I don't understand the distinction between the bird being "on a tree" (for which I think you mean *in a tree* or *on a branch*), and being "on top of"/"*at the* top of" the tree - it seems like this would be confusing/ambiguous in Italian, from what you've said.  Note also, that (in English) it could be "on a mountain" or "on top of a mountain" / "on a mountain top" (but probably not *in* the mountain, unless it's a canary in a mine).

Comment: @hunter2 So, your interest has been aroused. I am glad. I thought it was an interesting topic, but I confess I'm a bit disappointed with the quality of the posted answers. They're OK.. I suppose.

Comment: In what way are you disappointed with the existing answers? You have excellent answers to your 1st and 3rd questions (because they are answered definitively by an etymology and list respectively). So I can only guess no one is answering 2 to your satisfaction, the reason for English having many where Italian only has one. Is that the case?

Comment: @Mitch I would have appreciated a bit more depth and detail. And with the exception of Amory's answer no one has risen above one upvote, and most of them are mine in any case. So that tells me something too. And yes, the why has English got so many prepositions, I thought was an interesting topic.

Comment: @hunter2 to say a bird is *in* a tree, Italians basically use two different words, with no real difference in meaning: *nel* (*nella/nello/nei/negli/nelle*) = in the OR *dentro* = inside

Comment: The 'why so many prepositions' is simply a historical phenomenon. English has a mixed-up history from different invaders. Depth and detail would be to check out the etymologies of the specific terms and history of English in something that would be difficult to summarize here. Also consider that an interesting question may not have a definitive answer -or may have a definitive answer of 'there's nothing there' (your third question), just hard to prove.

Comment: @Mitch I realized that but I limited myself to asking one type of preposition or so I believed. Never mind, the question had ample exposure, I can't complain. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yup. Re. quality of answers - you *did* ask 3 questions about 4 different prepositions (coming from this side, at least) and, as Mitch points out, '#2' is a little hard to answer. If we were being really strict, it's not a great SE-format Question, and probably fits LinguisticsSE better than ELU.  Fortunately, we're not (what, me? never ...). Seriously - there can be overlap b/w SE sites and, as I said to another (ESL) 'ELUminary', I think most ELU folk would rather have a *good* ESLer (eg, you) ask a question that leans Linguistics than the bad ones who push us towards ELL.

Comment: I take that to mean that if a bird was on a lower branch of a tree, you could say *nel..* or *dentro* - but if it really was *inside* (eg, in a cavity in the trunk), you would say *dentro*.  Right?

Comment: @hunter2 In English "inside" is more specific and defined I think than in Italian. I suppose though if we were talking about owls then "dentro l'albero" would be absolutely correct! "Dentro", "nel" are nevertheless quite close in meaning, but I'm not an expert and I'm only speaking from a layperson's point of view.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/301739/50720 may assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**above** at a high level ORIGIN Old English abufan (as an adverb), from a- ‘on’ + bufan (from bi ‘by’ + ufan ‘above’).

**on** physically in contact with (but also at a high level) ORIGIN Old English on, an, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch aan and German an, from an Indo-European root shared by Greek ana .

**over** at a high level same as above) or beyond (ORIGIN Old English ofer, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch over and German über, from an Indo-European word (originally a comparative of the element represented by -ove in above) which is also the base of Latin super and Greek huper .

**on top of** this is showing or identify that something is highest in the order of other things.

**on top of** *1* on the highest point or uppermost surface of: a town perched on top of a hill. • so as to cover; over: trays stacked one on top of another. • in close proximity to: we all lived on top of each other. *2* in command or control of: he couldn't get on top of his work. *3* in addition to: on top of everything else, he's a brilliant linguist.

(same Apple dictionary source)

Could **over** be similar to sopra? in application rather than meaning? overuse, overcoat, overseen, overhead, overhaul, overhand, overflow

There seems to be an English obsession (historical) with this desire of knowing where something is in relation to other things. Think on the reason why *this* and *that* code for proximity. Why is that important? short answer, we don't know.

etymology from Apple dictionary (Version 2.2.3 (118.5). Holmes (2001:329 -An Introduction to Sociolinguistics) raises this question on *this* v *that* and proximity...and why it seems important to code for it.

Comment: citations added above

Comment: I'm not convinced by the *this* *that* argument, I think it's a poor example and I'm pretty certain most languages have words which express the difference between an object close at hand and one which is further away: "[...] while English speakers would have difficulty in interpreting the significance of the fact that the English demonstratives *this* vs *that* code degrees of proximity of the speaker [...]

Comment: I've just realized that your definition of "on top of" is a figure of speech as in "on top of that..." In my example, *on top of the furniture* I'm talking about position of place and not the order of things.

Comment: I think it can denote position of place as well. See edit above.

Comment: Yes, it's much better now. It completes your answer more. :)

Answer (score 6):

*Need* is an odd word to use.  Does English *need* four words here?  No, as Italian apparently does not, but as an English speaker I can spot plenty of points of confusion.  Does English *need* plurals?  Not really, as Japanese doesn't pluralize ("5 apple" implies 5 apples, so why bother putting an "s" on the end?) but again, I like to have the specificity.  Do languages *need* to have male or female words?  No, because English does not, yet plenty of other languages specify la/le/un/une and so forth.

Specificity is a nice thing to have, I think, and so I'd rather say mascara is on the eyelashes but eyebrows are above the eyelashes, and I wear a coat over my clothes but seawater got on my clothes while washing over it, but I don't *need* to.

Comment: I know my request might sound a bit petulant or begging the question. But I'm curious as to whether the English language had these different prepositions to start off with, or did it begin by having only two or three?  Which ones came later into being, and why? Which were forced upon by virtue of invasion, which were loaned, if any, during its long history?

Comment: It started off with Germanic prepositions and then got invaded by Romance prepositions, from Latin (several waves over the course of a millennium) and French (one big wave that lasted 400 years). Do we **need** them? Maybe, maybe not; how could one tell? But it's clear that we use them. In English the impulse is to find a single word with a single meaning, and most people believe that's the way language works (It doesn't, but that doesn't bother English speakers).

Comment: One reason for this attitude is because we no longer have any morphology left, unlike Romance languages. So we have to have one word _rat_ and another word _mouse_, one word _chair_ and another _couch_, where Spanish simply uses diminutive (_-(c)ito_) or augmentative (_-on_) affixes to form words from the same root.

Comment: @JohnLawler why don't you write this in an answer? For me this is still relatively new. In Italian there are similar diminutives and augmentives such as. "ino/a", "one" (OH-ne) issimo/a etc. As in *altissima*, *piccolissimo* and *piccolina*. Thank you for your comments. Much appreciated..

Comment: There are a few old jokes along these lines.   A sign or salesman says "A nickel for a pickel" / so the customer says "And how much for just this *pickelini*?" / "For that *pickelini*, just a *nickelini*!"

Answer (score 1):

"Which English words, if any, contain the preposition, on, coupled with a concrete noun to form one word..."

*Online* springs to mind. There are others, eg *onboard*. They might begin as separate words but become one word through common usage. Onboard = going on board of the ship. This is common as long as it doesn't lead to ambiguity.

> John was busy on line one. (ie on the phone)
>  John was busy online.

Similarly words like *e-mail* tend to lose their hyphens over time and become *email*.

Comment: *Online* of course!

Comment: Onlooker, onset.

Answer (score 1):

We do have the prefix ***supra*** in English which is equivalent in meaning.

According to m-w.com

> Definition of SUPRA- 1 : super- 2a  2 : transcending
>    See supra- defined for kids » Origin of SUPRA- Latin,
>   from supra above, beyond, earlier; akin to Latin super over — more at
>   over

Comment: can you give me any examples? I can't think of any offhand.

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Supraman* - n. an aviator // (This is a joke, made earlier in Catch-22, a excellent novel.  It would mean that, but it's not a real word.   I'm annoyed to realize that I can't think of any non-joke examples offhand, but will return when I do.)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the context is not enough to distinguish the different kinds of "sopra". In my kitchen, the microwave is on the counter. In some fancier kitchens it is above the counter.  Bridges are usually above or over the water, but sometimes (for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacey_V._Murrow_Memorial_Bridge) they can be on the water.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between "above" the water and "over" the water? Is there any *real* difference? But I agree there is a difference between "on" and "above" the counter. (I'm trying to think what it is in Italian!" :)

Comment: For bridges, I'd consider "above the water" and "over the water" synonymous; I intended only to point out the difference from "on the water.

Comment: Thanks for replying! For the microwave above the counter bit, in Italian we say it is "inbuilt", rather than "sopra" for obvious reasons. And the link to the bridge has a proper name, a floating bridge, which would be the same in Italian too!

Comment: Regarding bridges: consider [The Bridge on the River Kwai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bridge_on_the_River_Kwai), which is a nifty piece of wordplay. "On the river" denotes a geographical location (although you wouldn't usually use it to describe a bridge - you have "property on the river", for example), and it also describes the bridge's condition at the end of the story, when it's been partially demolished (SPOILER ALERT!) and is literally "on the river".

Comment: @MT_Head I liked how you backed up Andreas's answer.